# Can a Java argument be type-bound by a Class contained in another object?

Tags: java, generics, parameters

NOTE: This question is primarily theoretical; I've since given up on using this *immediately*, as everything I've thought up overcomplicates my code and smells a little like an antipattern. However, I find it interesting in theory and would love the community's help with it.

I'm refurbing some code written around the turn of the century for image manipulation; beginning by chopping apart a single class with a lot of redundancies into a number of BiFunction filters. They each accept a BufferedImage and an intensity (Double), and return a new BufferedImage. Of course, a lot of these image filters have additional concerns, like radius-of-effect or another intensity, and if I'm going to chain them efficiently, I would like to be able to set these as "uniforms" (or quasi-constants) before use.

My current method is simply to extend my ImageFilter class further, and set the uniforms as Bean-style properties. What I initially thought of doing was constraining them to a generic class that was held in an interface, and having something along the lines of:

```
public void addProperty(Uniform<T> property, T type)
```

in there, where T is specified entirely by the Uniform.

The original class kept all of these uniforms in a HashMap by String name,  but that's the beginning of a lot of bad habits and I clean it up every time I see it. If a misspelling causes code to misfire, it's irresponsible code. I would prefer to just use a Singleton there, like a grown up.

So, in summary, is it possible in Java to bind a parameter type to the generic of another parameter? If so, how? If not, does anyone know of any plans to extend Java Generics in the future, in such a manner?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: How hard do you think it might be to try it out and tell us what the compiler says?

Comment: @HankD I think I already explained that it's known to not be valid code. It doesn't compile. If you are to literally enter that code, the compiler will object that T can't be resolved to a type. The question is, is this a general truth, or is there a syntax or pattern that resolves the issue?

Comment: still not sure what you mean, why `public <T> void addProperty(Uniform<T> property, T type)` isn't what you want?

Comment: ok, so a Uniform is something that holds a property value, a way of adding arbitrary properties to your filter, and T is the value you assign to that property?

Comment: Assuming that's true, if Uniform will hold the T value, why not set in the Uniform before the addProperty, when you still know its actual type, and not worry about the generic type in addProperty?

Comment: A great suggestion; I'll try that and see if I can clear some of this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible all we have to do is define the type parameter on the method itself. Check the example below.

public class Uniform {

```
}
public class ImageFilter {
    //store in a list which can store any type of Uniform
    List<Uniform<?>> uniformList = new ArrayList<Uniform<?>>();

    //store in a map which can store any type of uniform and uses type as key
    Map<Class<?>, Uniform<?>> uniformMap = new HashMap<>();

    //Type parameter 'T' on the method itself
    public <T> void addProperty(Uniform<T> property, T type) {
        uniformList.add(property);
        uniformMap.put(type.getClass(), property);
    }
}
{
    //sample usage
    new ImageFilter().addProperty(new Uniform<>(), "test");
    new ImageFilter().addProperty(new Uniform<>(), new Double(2.0));
}
```

Following is sample usage

```
new ImageFilter().addProperty(new Uniform<>(), "test"); 
//or
new ImageFilter().addProperty(new Uniform<String>(), "test");
//if for some reason JVM can't infer the type itself, it can be set manually
new ImageFilter().<String>addProperty(new Uniform<String>(), "test");
```

See this [link for more information.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html)

Comment: Works nicely; though I'm hoping to keep my Uniforms (Shader-speak, btw) in a Map, not a List; I'll do a little research on how that can be done before I formally pick an answer. Generally I'm bumping into a  Thanks for the time. (Citation: "The method put(TypeInferment.Uniform<?>, capture#1-of ?) in the type Map<TypeInferment.Uniform<?>,capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (TypeInferment.Uniform<T>, T)")

Comment: @MichaelEricOberlin Modified the code to support map. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Your Map version works nicely. I still see a better way to do what I was trying to do; but I understand Java generics much better now. My thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, you can post your answer also. That will provide more options to the viewers.